# How to put section number into the right margin?

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, titlesec

With or without the use of `titlesec` package, how it's possible to put the section number (i.e. `\thesection`) on the right margin? I have literally no idea. I have tried to do some experiments but without any luck.

MWE:

```
%!TEX program = xelatex
\documentclass[
    draft=false,     % final mode 
    paper=portrait,
    twoside=false,
    open=right,
    parskip=full,
    headings=big,
    version=last, %
    italian, % language (passed to babel and other packages)
            % (ngerman, english, french, ...)
]{scrbook} % Classes: scrartcl, scrreprt, scrbook

% ----------------------
% DIMENSIONI PAGINA
% ----------------------
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0.3cm}
\setlength{\textwidth}{0.7\textwidth}
\setlength{\marginparwidth}{2\marginparwidth}


\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath}  % advanced math symbols pkg
\usepackage{amsthm, amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % utf8 encoding
\usepackage{graphicx} % pictures support
\usepackage{longtable} % table on multiple pages support
\usepackage[italian]{babel} % language support
\usepackage{enumitem} % custom enumeration support
\usepackage{rotating} % Rotating pictures support
\usepackage{floatrow} % Support for floated images
\usepackage{hyperref} % Support for href in toc
\usepackage{marvosym} % Currency symbols
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Fancy headers
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{afterpage} % Permette di mettere i numeri di pagina nel footer se si usa il package Fancyhdr
\usepackage{textcomp} % Package for copyright glyph
\usepackage[newfloat]{minted} % Package for highlight code
\usepackage{appendix} %Package for appendices
\usepackage{chngcntr} %Package for list of figures numeration
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{mwe}


% ----------------------
% CUSTOMIZATION CAPITOLI
% ----------------------
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{blindtext}

%\input{preamble/style-chapter}

\renewcommand*{\sectionformat}{%
  \llap{\thesection\enskip}%
}

\renewcommand*{\subsectionformat}{%
  \llap{\thesubsection\enskip}%
}

%\renewcommand*{\raggedsection}{\raggedleft} % Allinea a destra i titoli
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\raggedleft\normalfont\Large\bfseries} % format
  %{\makebox[0pt][l]{ % label
  % \makebox[\dimexpr\textwidth+\marginparsep-1.3cm][r]{
  %   \thesection
  % }}
  %}
  {\makebox[0pt][r]{#1 \hspace*{0.01cm}\thesection}}
  {0pt} % sep
  {\phantomsection} % before

% ----------------------
% FOOTNOTE AL MARGINE
% ----------------------
\usepackage{marginfix} % --> gestisce correttamente il posizionamento ai margini
\usepackage[%
   bottom,      % Footnotes appear always on bottom. This is necessary
   stable,      % Make footnotes stable in section titles
   perpage,     % Reset on each page
   side,       % Place footnotes in the margin
   ragged,      % Use RaggedRight
   marginal,
   norule,     % suppress rule above footnotes
   multiple,    % rearrange multiple footnotes intelligent in the text.
]{footmisc}
\setlength{\footnotemargin}{0.1mm} % --> distanza numero di nota a pie di pagine e testo
\definecolor{footnotecolor}{RGB}{78, 78, 78}
\def\footnotelayout{\raggedright\color{footnotecolor}} % --> raggedright coincide con text-align:left


% ----------------------
% CAPTION CUSTOMIZATION
% ----------------------
\usepackage[
    format=plain, 
    justification=raggedright,
    singlelinecheck=false
]{caption}
\captionsetup{figurename=FIGURE, labelsep=colon}
\captionsetup[figure]{font={color=footnotecolor,it,footnotesize},labelfont={color=black,bf,it,scriptsize}}
\captionsetup[listing]{font={color=footnotecolor,it,footnotesize},labelfont={color=black,bf,it,scriptsize}}
\renewcommand*{\figureformat}{ % --> elimina un punto di troppo sulla numerazione delle figure
    \figurename~\thefigure
       %  \autodot% DELETED
}

% ----------------------
% FLOATING
% ----------------------
\floatsetup{
    margins=hangright,
    capposition=beside,
    capbesideposition={bottom,right},
    floatwidth=\textwidth
}

\begin{document}
  \setminted{linenos,autogobble, frame=lines, framesep=3mm, tabsize=2, fontsize=\footnotesize,baselinestretch=1} %IMPOSTAZIONI 
  \chapter{Chapter}
  \blindtext\footnote{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras accumsan rutrum dictum. Nunc volutpat egestas 
  ante non efficitur. Sed pellentesque vulputate scelerisque.}
  \blindtext
  \section{Section}
  \blindtext
\end{document}
```

This is the current result:
[image: Current result]

This is what I would like to achieve:
[image: Desidered result]

Comment: Using `titlesec` with `scrbook` is discouraged (and might even be disallowed in future releases).

Comment: @egreg yes, I read more than once, but I don't know any alternatives. Achieving my same result with the KOMA-Script features I think would be 20x more lines of code!

Comment: @toioski I would rather say about 3x, but if you are that restrictive about the number of lines...

Comment: @TeXnician I am not restrictive, never said it. Mine was just a consideration. As you can read from the question, I don't really care about the type of solution.

Comment: Do you want it on the right side on each page or just on odd pages?

Comment: Are you tied to `scrbook`? Why not `memoir`?

Comment: @TeXnician it's a single sided document, so right side of each page

Comment: @egreg more yes than no. I mean that I have written the whole document starting from `scrbook` so I am pretty sure that the change will break something. Anyway, I can give a try. Are you able to solve the problem with `memoir`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can redefine `\sectionlinesformat`:

```
\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\textcolor{blue}{\thesection\autodot}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\rmfamily}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\raggedleft#4\makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip\marginparsep#3}}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}#4}% use original definition for subsection, subsubsection etc.
}
\makeatother
```

Example without the unrelated packages and settings:

```
\documentclass[
    draft=false,
    paper=portrait,
    twoside=false,
    open=right,
    parskip=full,
    headings=big,
    version=last,
    %italian,
]{scrbook} % Classes: scrartcl, scrreprt, scrbook


\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[protrusion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{blindtext}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{showframe}% to show the page layout
\usepackage{hyperref} % load as last package

\renewcommand*\sectionformat{\textcolor{blue}{\thesection\autodot}}
\addtokomafont{section}{\rmfamily}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*\sectionlinesformat[4]{%
  \ifstr{#1}{section}
    {\raggedleft#4\makebox[0pt][l]{\hskip\marginparsep#3}}
    {\@hangfrom{\hskip#2#3}#4}% use original definition for subsection, subsubsection etc.
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\Blindtext[2]
\section{Section}
\blindtext
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]